# GameRequestTracker: Got two responses with same content but with different ETags

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm building a second version of an Android application I wrote that uses Google Play Services. It uses the same game ids and signing key as the first. I'm seeing a new message in logcat about different ETags:

```
12-17 15:24:02.458: E/GamesRequestTracker(22567): Got two responses with the same content but  different ETags: URL https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/achievements?language=en_US, Content hash -405891742, previous ETag "<snipped: an ETag>", new ETag "<snipped: another ETag"
```

The ETags in the message are in the format "XXXXXXX/YYYYYY" where in both tags, the YYYYYY part is identical. The XXXXXX part is different.

What could cause this message?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the same error... and after several hours, I found my problem :

I have overridden the method "OnActivityResult", but I missed to call :

```
super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
```

Hope it will help you !